# QGIS contour layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

I have a contour layer with 50m interval for the sea and the land. I want to keep only the labels for the sea, specificaly I want to appear only the rates<=0. Do you know any expression to do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to set a label based on a condition, like `if("height" > 0,'',"height")`?

Comment: Do you want to hide only the labels above sea level, or the contours above sea level as well?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a single dem for the land and the sea together. So i created the contours from that. I want to hide and the contours above the sea level as well, as I want to separate the sea of the land.For the case of the bathymetry, I want to show only the labels with the negative values and the value of shoreline. But i have one shapefile from dem with the positive and negative values together. I hope to help you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. To hide contours, in the layer panel bring the contours layer below the layer representing the land mass.
2. To show only labels for contours <=0, use this expression for labeling: `if ("elevation" <=0, "elevation",'')`